# Position and Permission on Flutter Geolocator is not type

Tags: flutter, geolocation

Hi I'm getting the below error, on the code below with Geolocator 7.2.0 added also did the permission on the android.

error: Undefined class 'LocationPermission'. (undefined_class at [location] lib\main.dart:26)
error: Undefined class 'Position'. (undefined_class at [location] lib\main.dart:28)
error: Undefined name 'LocationAccuracy'. (undefined_identifier at [location] lib\main.dart:29)

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Location App',
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: location2(),
    );
  }
}

class location2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _location2State createState() => _location2State();
}

class _location2State extends State<location2> {
  LocationPermission permission;
  getlocation() async {
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    print(position);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Location'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            getlocation();
          },
          child: Text('get location'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61084016/how-do-i-solve-problem-with-geolocation-in-flutter did it resolve issue ?

Comment: Nah it doesn't work